# How to set up identity framework database on SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, asp.net-4.5

I am starting to look at the entity framework and especially identity. I am making an API to be used by an ASP.NET website. The problem I am having is I am used to the aspnet_regsql exe that is used by ASP.NET membership. I need to setup my application database so it has the correct tables and procedures for identity but I just cannot find out how too. I can then use the tables to link to my application tables.

So in short how can i setup the identity framework on a SQL server database?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project: [ASP.NET Identity Database](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6780f8e4-d204-4e88-83c2-853098727ffb) (project template), it can help to create and customize ASP.NET Identity Database manually with [SSDT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/tools.aspx).